# How to write a loop to extract articles from website archive which links to numerous external sources?

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to extract articles for a period of 200 days from Time dot mk archive, e.g. http://www.time.mk/week/2016/22. Each day has top 10 headings, each of which link to all articles related to it (at bottom of each heading "e.g. 320 поврзани вести". Following this link leads to a list of all related articles.

This is what I've managed so far:

```
`library(rvest) 
url = ("http://www.time.mk/week/2016/22") 
frontpage = read_html(url) %>%
html_nodes(".other_articles") %>%
html_attr("href") %>%
paste0()
mark = "http://www.time.mk/"
frontpagelinks = paste0(mark, frontpage)`
```

## by now I access primary links going to related news

The following extracts all of the links to related news for the first heading, from where I clear my data for only those links that I need.

```
final = list()
final = read_html(frontpagelinks[1]) %>%
html_nodes("h1 a") %>%
html_attr("href")%>%
paste0()`
```

My question is how I could instruct R, whether via loop or some other option so as to extract links from all 10 headings from "frontpagelinks" at once - I tried a variety of options but nothing really worked.

Thanks!

EDIT

Parfait's response worked like a charm! Thank you so much. 
I've run into an inexplicable issue however after using that solution.

Whereas before, when I was going link by link, I could easily sort out the data for only those portals that I need via:

a1onJune = str_extract_all(dataframe, ".*a1on.*")

Which provided me with a clean output: [130] "a1on dot mk/wordpress/archives/618719"

with only the links I needed, now if I try to run the same code with the larger df of all links I inexplicably get many variants of this this:

"\"alsat dot mk/News/255645\", **\"a1on dot mk/wordpress/archives/620944\",** , \"http://www dot libertas dot mk/sdsm-poradi-kriminalot-na-vmro-dpmne-makedonija-stana-slepo-tsrevo-na-balkanot/\",

As you can see in bold it returns my desired link, but also many others (I've edited out most for clarity sake) that occur both before and after it.

Given that I'm using the same expression, I don't see why this would be happening.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Simply run `lapply` to return a list of links from each element of *frontpagelinks*

```
linksList <- lapply(frontpagelinks, function(i) {
                 read_html(i) %>%
                     html_nodes("h1 a") %>%
                     html_attr("href")
             })
```